# Searching a string file

Tags: c#

This is an extract of 1 record in a text file:
"Aggie Ngwenya#15.99#FULL-TIME"

I need to check if the last bit after the second "#" is true.
In other words if it is "FULL-TIME" then I extract the rest of that line, if it is not true then ignore it and move on to the next line of text.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried, so far? Also, could you post one complete line of this file?

Comment: That is one complete line. Every line has 3 bits of info separated by the 2 "#"
Here is another line: "Altus de Bruyn#16.20#PART-TIME"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format is constant (each line has three parts delimited by '#'), you could do something like:

```
string[] parts = line.Split('#');
if (parts[2] == "FULL-TIME") DoStuff();
```

It is probably wise to add some error handling to react well to input that does not meet your expectation, e.g. check the length of *parts*, perhaps do a case insensitive compare if casing can be an issue.